# How to "rebuild" a $resource from a factory in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm implementing my own API-Token system into my AngularJS-Laravel project, so the API-Token is sent over $http using headers. The thing is, when a user logs in, it sets the API token in the API factory, but the $resource doesn't get updated.

```
myApp.factory('Api', ['$resource', '$http', '$cookies',function($resource, $http, $cookies) {
    var baseURL = 'an api url';
    var APIToken = $cookies.token;

    return {
        SetToken: function(token) {
            APIToken = token;
            console.log(APIToken);
        },

        Authenticator: function(data,callback) {
            $http({
                url: baseURL + 'auth', 
                method: "GET",
                params: data
            }).success(callback);
        },
        Authors: $resource(baseURL + "journalists/:id", {id: '@id'}, {
            update: {
                method:'PUT',
                headers: { 'API-Token': APIToken }
            },
            query: {
                method:'GET',
                isArray: true,
                headers: { 'API-Token': APIToken }
            }
        }),
    };
}]);
```

The most interesting part is the `headers: { 'API-Token': APIToken }` part. The problem is that when `SetToken` is called, the `headers` won't get updated. Is there any way around this? Am I using the wrong function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$resource` object is created and setup only once when it is called.  It doesn't access the `APIToken` variable every time you make a call to one of its functions.  In order to make the code above work, you would have to call `SetToken()` before you call `Authors()` because once you call `Authors()`, the `$resource` object is created and will use the value of `APIToken` at that moment.  I don't know of any way to do what you want and still use the `$resource` service.  You might have to just use the `$http` service directly, like you're doing for your `Authenticator` function.

```
Authors: {
    update: function(obj){
        $http({
            url: baseURL + 'journalists/' + obj.id, 
            method: "PUT",
            params: obj
        });
    },
    query: function(obj){
        $http({
            url: baseURL + 'journalists/' + obj.id, 
            method: "GET",
            params: obj
        });
    },
})
```

Or something like that.  Hope that helps.

Comment: That was exactly the way to go. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!